# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, console, mime

I've created an HTML and a Javascript file and have linked them, using  in the HTML's . When I open the Javascipt file (in Chrome or in Firefox), I do inspect and go to the console - which is completely empty. There is text in my Javascript file, which starts with "console.log" so it should appear in the console. When I do refresh on this console, I see for a split second the following message: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/Javascript", followed by the file's location.

I've done the same action many times before, so I'm wondering if I should change something in my laptop's settings? It's not working on previous Javascript files anymore either (whereas it did work on these same files previously).

I'm curious what's going wrong? Please try to explain like you would to a 5-year-old - I've only just started learning Javascript so I want to make sure I understand :-)

Comment: Update: So I now know what the problem is (or rather: was). I should've opened the index.html file (the one that was linked *to* the app.js file) and run the devtools and then the console off of that file - NOT the app.js file. Oops. I hope this will help others as well!

Comment: Post it as an an actual answer below, rather than just a comment :)